# iFrame wont size correctly

Tags: html, windows, silverlight, iframe, media

I am trying to put this live video in my public access channels website. This is the embedding that they (att-uverse) sent me. The problem is that it doesn't show the controls, but has white space above the video around the size that the controls should be.

```
<iframe src="http://video.discovervideo.com/dvme/play/wm/?video=http://video.discovervideo.com/accounts/boltonct/pub.asx&w=320&h=240&stretch=fit&start=true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" class="video" style="width: 320px; height: 240px">
```

I have tried making it a block and changing the positioning, but I can't seem to get rid of the white space. I have gotten the controls to show with the use of expanding the height.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best I could manage:

```
<iframe src="http://video.discovervideo.com/dvme/play/wm/?video=http://video.discovervideo.com/accounts/boltonct/pub.asx&w=320&h=240&stretch=fit&start=true" width="340px" height="254px" scrolling="auto">
```

Comment: Thanks for the help i will talk with discovervideo

Answer (score 0):

The white space at the top appears to be part of the video content that is being sent to you.

I had to update my Microsoft Silverlight install on my Macbook Pro to get the video to play and once it did it had the video controls at the bottom of the video as you would expect.

Comment: odd i tried that no luck, oh well i will have a talk with the provider.